# PHP sql query isn't returning anything

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

The following PHP code:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','abcde');

if (!$dbc) {
die('Not Connected:' . mysql_error ());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db ('db_test', $dbc);

if (!$db_selected) {
die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}

$query="SELECT * FROM 140423 WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans'";
//add "result"
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$query) {
die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}

echo $result;
```

Doesn't return anything.

Should I be using print instead of echo?

Also, if I change

```
echo $result;
```

To

```
echo 'whatever';
```

it returns "whatever" on my post.

Help?

Comment: the return value of mysql_query is a resource

Comment: Check out the [`mysql_query` examples at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: What happens when you copy and paste the query into mysql and run it? Are there any results being returned there?

Comment: Wrap your table name in backticks. Table names cannot start or be exclusively made of numbers. Plus, if you're looking to view data, you need to loop through it. You can't just `echo $result;` and expect data to magically appear.

Comment: Better still, don't give your table name a number for a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

> *Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.*

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html**

Which is exactly what you're doing, and should not be doing.

***Solution:***

1. Choose a different name for your table, one consisting of letters preferably.
2. Use backticks around the table name.

*Plus,* if you wish to view data, you need to use a loop.

**I.e.:**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `140423` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans'";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
            {
                $var = $row["column"]; // the column of your choice
            }

        echo $var;
```

---

Rewrite:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','abcde');

if (!$dbc) {
die('Not Connected:' . mysql_error ());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db ('db_test', $dbc);

if (!$db_selected) {
die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}

$query="SELECT * FROM `140423` WHERE GAME='Clash of Clans'";
//add "result"
$result=mysql_query($query);

// as pointed out already
    if (!$result) {
    die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
    }

echo $result; // this is up to you

// if you want to see data from your table, loop through it.

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
            {
                $var = $row["column"]; // the column of your choice
            }

        echo $var;
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query returns a resource or false.  You need to manipulate the resource with one of the various fetch functions.

Instead of looking if `$query` is false, you should be looking if `$result` is false.

```
if (!$result) {
die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: should still have output saying its a resource not a blank, so its not really an "answer"

Comment: @Dagon, judging by the code, it is most likely returning false and therefore not echoing anything because the query failed.  If you echo false, it won't echo anything.

Comment: I updated my answer to look for $result, not $query.

Answer (score 0):

After that

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$query) {
die ("Can't Connect :" .mysql_error());
}
```

Use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['YourTableFieldName'];
}
```

OR use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    // If you want to display all results from the query at once:
    print_r($row);

    // If you want to display the results one by one
    echo $row['YourTableFieldName1'];
    echo $row['YourTableFieldName2']; 
}
```

Comment: This is great. So, now I have a script that echos a single item of data, in this case is returns "Clash of Clans".

Comment: Is there a way to use this to search multiple tables at once within a database?

Comment: Lastly, is there a way to echo the results with spaces? Right now they return as one line.